# Can you query a MongoDB database using mongoose using 2 expressions?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to create a Critterpedia for Animal Crossing as a back-end learning experience. I have pulled the JSON from an API that contains ALL fish with an array of months available in the northern hemisphere. My original query, that searches for all fish available this month, works just fine.

```
let query = { fishMonthsNorth : thisMonth }
```

When I try to query fish available this month but NOT available next month, it returns undefined.

```
let query = { $and: [ 
        { fishMonthsNorth : thisMonth}, 
        { $not: {fishMonthsNorth: nextMonth}}
     ]}
```

Here is my full index route:

```
app.get('/critters', (req, res) => {
    const today = new Date();
    const lastMonth = today.getMonth();
    const thisMonth = today.getMonth() + 1;
    const nextMonth = today.getMonth() + 2;

    let query = { $and: [ 
        { fishMonthsNorth : thisMonth}, 
        { $not: {fishMonthsNorth: nextMonth}}
     ]}

    Fish.find(query, (err, thisMonthFish) => {
        res.render('index', {thisMonthFish : thisMonthFish})
    }); 
});
```

ps - I do realize I will run into issues with the Date() method and am working on a longer term solution.

Comment: `{ fishMonthsNorth: { $eq: null } }` does this helps you?

Comment: You can try this `{$and: [{fishMonthsNorth: thisMonth}, {fishMonthsNorth: {$ne: nextMonth}}]}`

Comment: @turivishal , That worked perfectly! Thank you. How would I go about doing the same thing for my Bugs and Sea Creatures databases and passing all 3 variables in 1 res.render() call?

Comment: I am not getting you exactly, you can ask new question or, if its related to this question then add in this question.